# BaseAdapter doesn't work in Fragment via PagerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, baseadapter, android-pageradapter

so I'm trying to make a PagerView via Fragments containing a multiple BaseAdapters in them, but I ran into a little problem with BaseAdapter, I have multiple Fragment, but I'll post 1 as an example

```
class SpellManagement : Fragment(){
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        listViewSpells?.adapter = AllSpells()

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_spell, container, false)
    }
}

class AllSpells: BaseAdapter() {
        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return player.learnedSpells.size/5+1
        }

        override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
            return position.toLong()
        }

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
            return "TEST STRING"
        }

        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, viewGroup: ViewGroup?): View {
            val rowMain: View

            val index:Int = if(position == 0) 0 else{
                position*5
            }
            if (convertView == null) {
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup!!.context)
                rowMain = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_spells_managment, viewGroup, false)
                val viewHolder = ViewHolder(rowMain.buttonSpellsManagment1,rowMain.buttonSpellsManagment2,rowMain.buttonSpellsManagment3,rowMain.buttonSpellsManagment4)
                rowMain.tag = viewHolder
            } else rowMain = convertView
            val viewHolder = rowMain.tag as ViewHolder
            viewHolder.buttonSpellsManagement1.setBackgroundResource(player.learnedSpells[index]!!.drawable)
            viewHolder.buttonSpellsManagement2.setBackgroundResource(player.learnedSpells[index+1]!!.drawable)
            viewHolder.buttonSpellsManagement3.setBackgroundResource(player.learnedSpells[index+2]!!.drawable)
            viewHolder.buttonSpellsManagement4.setBackgroundResource(player.learnedSpells[index+3]!!.drawable)

            viewHolder.buttonSpellsManagement1.setOnClickListener {

            }
            viewHolder.buttonSpellsManagement2.setOnClickListener {

            }
            viewHolder.buttonSpellsManagement3.setOnClickListener {

            }
            viewHolder.buttonSpellsManagement4.setOnClickListener {

            }

            return rowMain
        }

        private class ViewHolder(val buttonSpellsManagement1: Button, val buttonSpellsManagement2: Button, val buttonSpellsManagement3: Button, val buttonSpellsManagement4: Button)
}
```

I was originally using activities, but in the case of PagerView I've changed it to Fragment. What I know is, that I can't call `this` etc. what I found in java codes was in some cases getActivity() instead of `this`, which I couldn't find in Kotlin. So by saying that it could be in the `viewGroup!!.context` in the BaseAdapter.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline30"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/listViewSpells"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="87dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline7"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1925"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline11" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="83dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline10"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.05"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="86dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline14"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4825"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline7" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.63"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline13" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.774" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline16"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.92" />


    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="83dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline13"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.34"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline10" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewSpells"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline14"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline30"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewInfoSpell"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="141dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline9"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1.25"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline14"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline30" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline30"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline14"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline14"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline14"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: btw in case I change the 'listViewSpells?.adapter = AllSpells()' to 'listViewSpells.adapter = AllSpells()' calls error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: listViewSpells must not be null"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... this was REALLY strange to me, the answer was to create a new ListView with the old nowadays not very used "view.FindViewById(...)" thingie, which I've never used before because of the plugins, that allows you to straight up write the name of the component such as "listView.adapter = ..." instead of external defining it by "view.findViewById(...)" thingie. Also with the combination of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53775717/baseadapter-doesnt-work-in-fragment-via-pagerview/53776064#53776064) by **MinnKhant**.The final code looks as follows:

```
class SpellManagement : Fragment(){
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.activity_spell_managment, container, false)

        val listView:ListView = view.findViewById(R.id.listViewSpells)
        listView.adapter = AllSpells()
        return view
    }
}
```

Cheers

Edit: or just write view.listViewSpells.adapter = AllSpells(), instead of findViewById(...)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do your adapter works after declaring a view. In activity, after calling onCreate method we can get a view for our other works. Its slighting different in fragments. We can have view after inflating your view.

First, create a view as a first line of your `onCreateView` function.

```
val view = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.activity_spells, container, false)
```

Second, return that view from your `onCreateView` function.
Finally, you can put(use) your other works between those. In that way, you can use the viwe (your fragment) as a variable `view`. Your `SpellManagement` class will be looks like this :

```
class SpellManagement : Fragment(){
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    val view = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.R.layout.activity_spells, container, false)
    \**

    Your other codes or works here

    *\
    listViewSpells?.adapter = AllSpells()

    return view
}
```

}

I think this might helps. Cheer!

Comment: It just does the same thing - it returns "java.lang.IllegalStateException: listViewSpells must not be null" without the "?" mark, and doesn't show anything with the "?" mark.